# MAPPEDBYTEBUFFER IS NOT VALID FLATBUFFER MODEL when loading tflite model file into project

Tags: java, android, tensorflow

The whole android project origins from tensorflow official's example called Camera2BasicFragment.
We edit it to meet our needs which is detect the people body motion.
However , when we tried to load the tflite file under the Asset folder, it arose some question.

> Have I written custom code : No
>
> OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04): OSX 10.12.3
>
> Mobile device: ASUS_X00ID
>
> TensorFlow installed from (source or binary):
>
> TensorFlow version (use command below): 1.14.0
>
> Python version: 3.6.9
>
> Bazel version (if compiling from source): None
>
> GCC/Compiler version (if compiling from source):None
>
> CUDA/cuDNN version: None
>
> GPU model and memory: None

this is the code we try to load the model
the error arrise at 
this line
when we trying to put it on our phone it throw into the catch and show the error message "JAVA.LANG.ILLEGALARGUMENTEXCEPTION:MAPPEDBYTEBUFFER IS NOT A VALID FLATBUFFER MODEL"
We assume it has something to do with the "MAPPREDBYTEBUFFER",but the problem is we did create a pretty simple project to test the load model process and showed no error.

```
private void trymodel(){
        String modelFile="LSTM_1.tflite";
        Interpreter tflite = null;
        try {
            tflite=new Interpreter(loadModelFile(CameraActivity.this));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            testmodel_but.setText(String.valueOf(e));
        }

        float[][][] inputX;
        inputX = new float[1][1][22];
        //random the array
        Random random=new Random();
        for( int i = 0 ; i < inputX.length ; i++ ) {
            for ( int j = 0 ; j < inputX[i].length ; j++ ) {
                for (int k=0;k < inputX[j].length ; k++){
                    inputX[i][j][k]= random.nextInt(101);
                }
            }
        }
```

the function we loadModelFile

```
 private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile(Activity activity) throws Exception {
            AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = activity.getAssets().openFd("LSTM_1.tflite");
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
            FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
            long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
            long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
            return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);

    }
```

Comment: Maybe you have not included the `noCompress "tflite"` in your build.gradle file. The model has been compressed because of its absence.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal yes i did included that line in my build.gradle file ,however, thank you for your response!